# Forward declaration doesn't work as expected in MQL

Tags: compiler-errors, include, mql4, mql5

I've 4 classes across 4 different files in the following hierarchy:

```
|-- Terminal (Chart)
|   |-- Chart (Draw, Market)
|   |   |-- Draw
|   |   |-- Market
```

<sup>In the brackets are class pointers which class implements as class variables.</sup>

So Draw and Market classes extends Chart, which extends Terminal. Although I still want to define some class pointer, so Terminal class it-self has `chart` pointer to Chart class.

The files are:

#### `Terminal.mqh`

```
// Forward declaration.
class Chart;
class Terminal;

// Includes.
#include "Chart.mqh"

class Terminal {
  protected:
    Chart *chart;
};
```

#### `Chart.mqh`

```
// Forward declaration.
class Chart;
class Terminal;

// Includes.
#include "Terminal.mqh"

class Chart : public Terminal {
  protected:
    // Includes.
    #include "Draw.mqh"
    #include "Market.mqh"

    // Class variables.
    Draw *draw;
    Market *market;
};
```

Note: The includes to `Draw` and `Market` files are placed after class definition just to make sure that the current `Chart` class is being defined at the time when these includes are loaded, and just before declaration of variables which are using it.

#### `Draw.mqh`

```
// Forward declaration.
class Chart;
class Draw;

#include "Chart.mqh"

class Draw : public Chart {
  // Some drawing methods.
};
```

#### `Market.mqh`

```
// Forward declaration.
class Chart;
class Market;

// Includes.
#include "Chart.mqh"

class Market : public Chart {
  // Some market methods.
};
```

To avoid any compiler errors while the includes are loaded, I'm making forward declaration, however the compilation still fails.

The errors are as follow (depending which file I'm trying to compile):

- `Terminal.mqh` (3 error(s), 0 warning(s))

  > 'Terminal' - struct undefined Chart.mqh   8   22
  >
  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Draw.mqh    7   21
  >
  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Market.mqh  8   23
- `Chart.mqh` (2 error(s), 0 warning(s))

  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Draw.mqh    7   21
  >
  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Market.mqh  8   23
- `Draw.mqh` (1 error(s), 0 warning(s))

  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Market.mqh  8   23
- `Market.mqh` (1 error(s), 0 warning(s))

  > 'Chart' - struct undefined    Draw.mqh    7   21

<sup>Tested in the latest build 1498.</sup>

The above errors are the same for both MQL4 and MQL5 compiler builds.

Is there any solution to above problem? I am missing anything?

To clarify, my goal is to keep each class in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to inherit a class from forward declaration.

So the files needs to be included after the class has been defined.

The following structure has been suggested to me:

#### `Terminal.mqh`

```
// Forward declaration.
class Chart;
class Terminal;

class Terminal {
  protected:
    Chart *chart;
};

// Includes.
#include "Chart.mqh"

// Terminal methods implementation
```

#### `Chart.mqh`

```
class Chart;
class Terminal;

// Includes.
#include "Terminal.mqh"

class Chart: public Terminal
  {
protected:
   Draw             *draw;
   Market           *market;

public:
   void  Test()
     {
      draw.Test();
      market.Test();
     }
  };

#include "Draw.mqh"
#include "Market.mqh"
```

#### `Draw.mqh`

```
#include "Chart.mqh"

class Draw : public Chart
  {
public:
   void Test()
     {
      this.Test();
     }
  };
```

#### `Market.mqh`

```
#include "Chart.mqh"

class Market : public Chart
  {
public:
   void Test()
     {
      this.Test();
     }
  };
```

Still not ideal, but at least it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

It should work,
at least I see no problems if classes are at one place:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I need them in separate files. The problem here is about compiling classes which are kept separately and include them in the right way.